# Windows - Move remote file to another remote location on same server

Tags: windows, file, move

i wonder how windows exactly handle these task:

i have a file on a shared folder: \\server\my_file.txt

And now i want to move (not copy) this file to: \\server\my new folder\my_file.txt

What does windows do exactly when i start the move progress from my local machine? Does it copy the file to my local machine before moving it into the new location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move a file to the same share it will be moved without transferring to your machine: `\\server\share\file.txt -> \\server\share\new folder\file.txt`

If you move a file to the different share it will be transferred to your machine and back to the destination share: `\\server\share1\file.txt -> your machine -> \\server\share2\new folder\file.txt`

Comment: Thanks ;-) I need this for a special move logic in one of my tools.